# Wordpress Custom From Handling

Tags: wordpress, forms

I've got a custom form I've built for taking payments with a certain gateway for various reasons.

```
<form id="paymentForm" action="/wp-admin/admin-post.php" method="post">
<input type="hidden" name="action" value="processPayment">
<!-- BUNCH OF DATA FIELDS -->
<input class="btn" name="Submit Payment" type="submit">
</form>
```

The form is setup like this, and the handling is done in functions.php like this:

```
function handlePaymentForm() {
        $data = array(
                "first_name"    => $_POST['fname'],
                "last_name"     => $_POST['lname'],
                "ccnumber"      => $_POST['ccnumber'],
                "ccexp"         => $_POST['ccexp'],
                "cvv"           => $_POST['cvv']
        );

        $endpoint = 'https://apiprocessing.com/transcation.php';
        $options = array(
                'method' => 'POST',
                'body'   => $data
        );

        $response = wp_remote_post($endpoint, $options);
        if (is_wp_error($response)) {
                error_log(print_r($response->get_error_message()));
        } else {
                if ($response == authorization condition) {
                        //success
                        wp_redirect(site_url('/welcome/'));
                        exit();
                } else {
                        //declined
                        wp_redirect(site_url('/form?error/')); //back to the form with error message
                        exit();
                }
        }
}

add_action('admin_post_nopriv_processPayment', 'handlePaymentForm');
add_action('admin_post_processPayment', 'handlePaymentForm');
```

I've shortened a lot of this, the form and the some of the data in the functions.php file. However, if I take out the wp_redirects and I `print_r` the $response variable, it stays on admin-post.php and is almost instant with kicking back the api response. I can't seem to get wp_redirect to work and if I instead do something like

```
<script>document.location.href="/welcome";</script>
```

instead of the wp_redirect it works too, but takes forever. I need help figuring out why wp_redirect doesn't work and why it takes so long to get to that point. I know it's not the api call because like I said I can print the $response variable almost immediately.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To get `wp_redirect` to work it's imperative to make sure there aren't any variables or data of any kind being printed or echoed or it will fail. Once this was resolved everything works as expected.